# change x axis scale im matplotlib imshow?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

The code is giving me the image below. I need to have more precision in the x-axis. Now I have next points in every 100 samples. But I'd love to have printed points more often(at each 50 samples).

For exampe(x axis): 
 - now i have: 0 100 200 ...
 - i want: 0 50 100 150 200 ...

Is it possible to make this image with a grid up at this image(draw lines at each printed point for the two-axis(x and y))?

```
Output:<br>
```

[image: output]

> Python code:
>   'energy' is numpy 2D array(60,736) of int32 type.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.imshow(energy, aspect=10)
ax.axes.set_aspect(aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the axis locator in the following way:

```
x = np.linspace(0,200,10)
y = x**2
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x,y)
```

Output:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x,y)

loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=50)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: it worked,thanks) any ideas how to make a grid to see the image more precise(for example to be able to see what coordinates of some points in the centre from the image)?

Comment: @CapJS Try `plt.grid(color='yellow')` to get a grid with a contrasting color.